# Требуется после нажатия кнопки "Добавить в базу" очистить все поля

Tags: php

Всем доброе время суток.Столкнулся с проблемой очищения полей после добавлениях их значений в БД.Подскажите как можно это осуществить, прикладываю код этой страницы:

```
<center>
<div class="container">
<h2><font  color="#6a5d4d" >Добавить книгу:</font></h2>

<form method="get" action="add_router.php">

<div class="radius"><table border=2>
 <tr>
  <td><label><font  color="#6a5d4d" >Название книги:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</font></label>
  <input required type="text" name="fname" value="<?php echo $_GET['fname'] ?>">
  </td>
  <td><label><font  color="#6a5d4d" >Автор*:</font></label>
  <select  name="fAuthor" id="" name="fAuthor" required="">
   <?php SelectAuthor($_GET['fAuthor']); ?>
  </select>
  <td><label><font  color="#6a5d4d" >Издательство*:</font></label>
  <select name="fPublisher" id="" name="fPublisher" required=""><?php companySelect($_GET['fPublisher']); ?>
  </select>
  </td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td><label><font  color="#6a5d4d" >Жанр*:</font></label><br>
  <select required="Добавьте информацию" name="fgenre" id="" name="fgenre"><option disabled="" value=""></option><?php genreSelect($_GET['fgenre']); ?>
  </select>
  <td><label><font  color="#6a5d4d" >Раздел:</font></label><br>
  <select required="Добавьте информацию" name="fClassifier" id=""><option disabled="" value=""></option><?php personSelect($_GET['fClassifier']); ?>
  </select>
  <td><label><font  color="#6a5d4d" >Средняя цена:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</font></label>
  <input  type="text" name="fPrice_in_rubles" value="<?php echo $_GET['fPrice_in_rubles'] ?>">
  </td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td><label><font  color="#6a5d4d" >Год издания:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</font></label><br>
  <input  required type="text" name="fyear" value="<?php echo $_GET['fyear'] ?>">
  </td>
  <td><label><font  color="#6a5d4d" >Тип обложки:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</font></label><br>
  <input type="text" name="fCover_Type" value="<?php echo $_GET['fCover_Type'] ?>">
  </td>
  <td><label><font  color="#6a5d4d" >Кол-во страниц:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</font></label>
  <input required type="text" name="fNumber_of_pages" value="<?php echo $_GET['fNumber_of_pages'] ?>">
  </td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td><label><font  color="#6a5d4d" >Оценка:*&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</font></label><br>
 <input  required type="text" name="fassessment" value="<?php echo $_GET['fassessment'] ?>">
  </td>
  <td><label><font  color="#6a5d4d" >ISBN:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</font></label><br>
 <input  type="text" name="fISBN" value="<?php echo $_GET['fISBN'] ?>">
  </td>
  <td><label><font  color="#6a5d4d" >Размер книги L*W*H:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</font></label>
  <input  type="text" name="fBook_size" value="<?php echo $_GET['fBook_size'] ?>">
  </td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td><label><font  color="#6a5d4d" >Вес книги в граммах:</font></label><br>
  <input  type="text" name="fWeight_of_the_book" value="<?php echo $_GET['fWeight_of_the_book'] ?>">
  </td>
  <td colspan = "2" ><h6 ><font size="3" color="#6a5d4d" >Описание:</font></h6>
  <textarea  name="fBrief_annotation" cols="60" rows="2"><?php echo $_GET['fBrief_annotation']; ?></textarea>
  </td>
 </tr>
</table></div><br>
<input type="submit" name="add_film"  value="Добавить в базу" /><br><br>
<input type="submit" name="add_person" value="Добавить автора" ><br><br>
<input type="submit" name="add_company" value="Добавить издательство" ><br><br>
<input type="submit" name="add_genre" value="Добавить жанр" ><br><br>
<input type="submit" name="add_classifier" value="Добавить раздел" ><br>
</form>
</div></center>
```

[image: Произвожу добавление книги, а поля остаются заполненными]

Comment: Очистить поля можно посредством jquery, либо сделав перезагрузку страниці

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужно просто добавить код, который будет задавать null input'ам, при нажатии add_film.

```
<?
if ($_POST['add_film']) {
   $_POST['названиеinput1'] = NULL;
   $_POST['названиеinput2'] = NULL;
   // и тд...
   $_POST['названиеinputN'] = NULL;
}
?>
```

Comment: Попробую, спасибо

Comment: @Михаил если код рабочий, отблагодарить всегда можно галочкой. Если нет - пишите, поправлю ответ

Comment: Ну я вроде попробовал, пока никаких изменений, всё также

Comment: Почему вы используете get запрос в input'ах? Ведь вы хотите добавить данные на сервер ==> нужно использовать post запрос.

Comment: Или вместо $_POST у меня в коде используйте $_GET или подстройте свой код под post'Ы в input'ах и посмотрите, какой из них будет эффективен

Answer (score 0):

Делайте AJAX отправку формы и очистку полей через JS.

или убирайте все такие записи из элементов формы:

```
<?php echo $_GET['fassessment'] ?>
```

Что бы элементы формы выглядели так:

```
<input  required type="text" name="fassessment" value="">
```

Comment: К сожалению, я не знаком с AJAX и только начинаю знакомство с PHP,неужели нет других вариантов?